# Change picture onmouseover only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I need to change picture on mouse over only once. So when mouse over - change picture and STOP, never get back to default image, keep the new one. I need this because default image is gif animated and mouse over is static png pictire and as people hold the mouse for a second animated picture comes back. Atleast to delay for 5 seconds onmouseout action.

Right now I use this javascript.

```
function onHover()
{
$("#menuImg").attr('src', 'images/mouseover_picture.png');
}

function offHover()
{
$("#menuImg").attr('src', 'images/default_picture.png');
}
```

html :

```
<img src="map.gif" id="menuImg" alt="info" width="415" height="380" usemap="#Europe" border="0" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();" />
```

Comment: Please make sure you use the jQuery tag if you are using it in your code

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the **[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** handler to fire it only once.

```
$('#menuImg').one('mouseenter', function() {   
  $(this).attr('src', 'images/mouseover_picture.png');   
});
```

Here's a very basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsmQU/) example showing it used with an alert.

Comment: Adding an example will be helpful to the OP as well as future readers.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the slow example

Answer (score 3):

For jQuery you can use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function to trigger the event only once.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWbpm/)

```
$('#menuImg').one('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
});
```

As pure JS solution, detach the event handler by assigning `null` to it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nnvp/)

```
var img = document.getElementById('menuImg');
img.onmouseover = function () {
    this.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
    img.onmouseover = null;
};
```

Comment: It looks like javascript you provide it is in conflict with maphighlight.js which I use it for my map http://alt-web.com/Scripts/maphighlight.js . Your script works only if I remove maphighlight.js